# PHP проблема со сравнением времени

Tags: php

Как проверить, насколько текущее время больше указанного?

Например:

```
$a = date("H:i"); // Текущее время
$b = "18:59";
```

Как узнать, насколько `$a` больше `$b` или наоборот?

Comment: Отнимаете второе число от первого. Полученную разность провряете на ваши более, менее, равно

Comment: А если это дата?

Comment: @Anatoly, проверяйте по дням или что там вам нужно. Раскладывайте дату на секунды и проверяйте на сколько одна больше второй

Comment: Убираете точки и приводите к числу.

Comment: Я вообще по линии java. В php вообще пустышка. Просто логически думаю. Могу за вас нагуглить

Comment: У вас дата в каком формате? Если хотите, могу написать вам пример

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы `$a = date("H:i");` далее `$b = "18:88 - $a"` `echo $b;` выдавало нормальный результат а не 18:88 - время

Comment: А что за `18:88` ?

Comment: Ну 18 - час, 88 - минута. Секунды мне не нужны

Comment: Простите, мне всегда казалось, что максимальная минута - это `59`. `18:59`, `19:00`

Comment: Я вот сейчас не понял как привести к числу

Comment: @Anatoly у Вас `18:88` - это строка или это `18 разделить на 88` ?

Comment: `$b = 18:88 - $a;` вот что, вряд ли это строка

Comment: @Anatoly *$a = date("H:i"); далее $b = "18:88 - $a" echo $b;* а что Вы тогда хотите сделать? 18 разделить на 88 - (текущий час разделить на текущую минуту) ?

Comment: Как `date("H:i")` может вернуть `18:88`. Или это пример неудачный?

Comment: Оно должно считать время. Допустим, я вместо **18:88** напишу `$b = 18:60 - $a` , где `$a = date("H:i")` но ведь оно всё-равно не посчитает мне результат

Comment: @Anatoly нет минут больше 59. во-вторых - Вам нужно сравнить два времени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите сравнивать время. Для сравнения времени можно использовать такой код:

```
$a = strtotime(date("H:i"));
$b = strtotime("18:30");
if($b > $a){
  echo "<b>B</b> больше <b>A</b> на: ".date("H:i", $b - $a); // Если A < B
}else if($b < $a){
  echo "<b>A</b> больше <b>B</b> на: ".date("H:i", $a - $b); // Если B < A
}else{
  echo "<b>B</b> и <b>A</b> равны и их разница равна: "."00:00"; // Если A = B
};
```

Comment: Да! теперь всё хорошо. Я модернизировал код + сделал подключение к БД и теперь: 1) Выдаёт `A больше B на: 02:21:46`, хотя  в БД ->time другое значение

Comment: 2) Оно сделалось в цикле `A больше B на: 02:21:43 A больше B на: 02:21:45 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:44 A больше B на: 02:21:47 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:43 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:42 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:42 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:46 A больше B на: 02:21:42 A больше B на: 02:21:46`, а я хотел что-бы для каждой ячейки в колонке считалось

Comment: Что теперь делать?)

Comment: Я кажется разобрался:)

Comment: @Anatoly, вы учтите, что date показывает не ваше время

Answer (score 0):

или возвращаете регуляркой(я могу и ошибиться): /:0-9_/, ф может и так /:n+_/, или так вообще

```
$x1 = $data; $x2 = $data;function getDetlaTime ($x1, $x2) 
{
    if( $x1<$x2 &&$ (x2-$x1)==1) {return $result}
    if( $x1<$x2 &&$ (x2-$x1)>1) {return $result2} 
}
```